# Opening a drawer component from my navigation bar component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, chakra-ui

I am using ChakraUI and react and I want to open my NavigationDrawer using a button on my NavigationBar. I need to call the useDisclosure from my drawer component in my bar compoment. How would I do that? I couldn't find online how to do this.

My NavigationDrawer: component

```js
import {
    Drawer,
    DrawerOverlay,
    DrawerContent,
    DrawerCloseButton,
    IconButton,
    useDisclosure,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { HamburgerIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons'
import { React } from 'react'

function NavigationDrawer() {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
    return (
        <>
            <IconButton icon={<HamburgerIcon />} aria-label='Open navigation drawer' variant='solid' onClick={onOpen}>
                Open
            </IconButton>
            <Drawer placement='left' onClose={onClose} isOpen={isOpen}>
                <DrawerContent>
                    <DrawerCloseButton aria-label='Open navigation drawer'></DrawerCloseButton>
                </DrawerContent>
            </Drawer>

        </>
    )
}
export default NavigationDrawer;
```

My NavigationBar component:

```js
// src/components/navigation/NavigationBar.jsx
import { IconButton, useColorMode,  Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { MoonIcon, SunIcon, HamburgerIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons'

function NavigationBar() {
    const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode()

    return (
        <>
            <Flex
                as="nav"
                align="center"
                justify="space-between"
                wrap="wrap"
                w="100%"
                mb={8}
                p={8}
                bg={"black"}

            >
                <IconButton icon={<HamburgerIcon />} aria-label='Open navigation drawer' variant='solid'>
                    Open
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton aria-label='Toggle theme' onClick={toggleColorMode} icon={colorMode === 'light' ? <SunIcon /> : <MoonIcon />} />
            </Flex>
        </>
    )
}
export default NavigationBar
```

How I combine my NavigationDrawer and NavigationBar:

```js
// src/components/navigation/Navigation.jsx
import NavigationDrawer from './NavigationDrawer';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';

function Navigation() {
    return (
        <>
            <NavigationDrawer />
            <NavigationBar />
        </>
    )
}
export default Navigation
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to move the useDisclosure hook up one level and pass the props down to the drawer and navigation bar.

```
//Navigation.jsx
import { useDisclosure } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import NavigationDrawer from './NavigationDrawer'
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar'

function Navigation() {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

  return (
    <>
      <NavigationDrawer isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} />
      <NavigationBar onClick={onOpen} />
    </>
  )
}
export default Navigation
```

```
//NavigationDrawer.jsx
import { Drawer, DrawerOverlay, DrawerContent, DrawerCloseButton } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { React } from 'react'

function NavigationDrawer({ isOpen, onClose }) {
  return (
    <Drawer placement="left" onClose={onClose} isOpen={isOpen}>
      <DrawerOverlay />
      <DrawerContent>
        <DrawerCloseButton aria-label="Open navigation drawer"></DrawerCloseButton>
      </DrawerContent>
    </Drawer>
  )
}
export default NavigationDrawer
```

```
//NavigationBar.jsx
import { IconButton, useColorMode, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { MoonIcon, SunIcon, HamburgerIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons'

function NavigationBar({ onClick }) {
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode()

  return (
    <Flex as="nav" align="center" justify="space-between" wrap="wrap" w="100%" mb={8} p={8} bg={'black'}>
      <IconButton
        icon={<HamburgerIcon />}
        aria-label="Open navigation drawer"
        variant="solid"
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        Open
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton
        aria-label="Toggle theme"
        onClick={toggleColorMode}
        icon={colorMode === 'light' ? <SunIcon /> : <MoonIcon />}
      />
    </Flex>
  )
}
export default NavigationBar
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, Here is the Steps.

You need to create a Drawer component that utilizes ChakraUI's useDisclosure hook to control its visibility.

Within the Drawer component, include a button that toggles the visibility of the drawer.

Import the Drawer component into your Navbar component.

The button from the Drawer component will then be displayed wherever you place it within the Navbar, and the Drawer will automatically open in its designated position.

---

### Drawer

---

```
import { CloseIcon, HamburgerIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import {
  Drawer,
  DrawerBody,
  DrawerFooter,
  DrawerHeader,
  DrawerOverlay,
  DrawerContent,
  DrawerCloseButton,
  useDisclosure,
  Button,
  Input,
  IconButton,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useRef } from "react";

const Sidebar = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const btnRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
// This Button will be displayed wherever you place <Sidebar/> within the Navbar.
      <IconButton
        size={"md"}
        icon={isOpen ? <CloseIcon /> : <HamburgerIcon />}
        aria-label={"Open Menu"}
        display={{ md: "none" }}
        onClick={onOpen}
        ref={btnRef}
      />
      <Drawer
        isOpen={isOpen}
        placement="right"
        onClose={onClose}
        finalFocusRef={btnRef}
      >
        <DrawerOverlay />
        <DrawerContent>
          <DrawerCloseButton />
          <DrawerHeader>Create your account</DrawerHeader>

          <DrawerBody>
            <Input placeholder="Type here..." />
          </DrawerBody>

          <DrawerFooter>
            <Button variant="outline" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button colorScheme="blue">Save</Button>
          </DrawerFooter>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  );
};
export default Sidebar;
```

---

### Navbar

---

```
import {
  Box,
  Flex,
  Avatar,
  HStack,
  Text,
  IconButton,
  Button,
  Menu,
  MenuButton,
  MenuList,
  MenuItem,
  MenuDivider,
  useDisclosure,
  useColorModeValue,
  Stack,
  useColorMode,
  Link as ChakraLink,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { HamburgerIcon, CloseIcon, MoonIcon, SunIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { logOut } from "@/store/authSlice";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

interface ChildProps {
  DrawerRef: null | string;
}

const Links = [
  { title: "App", link: "/app" },
  { title: "About", link: "/app/about" },
  { title: "Services", link: "/app/services" },
];

const NavLink = ({ link, title }: { link: string; title: string }) => {
  return (
    <ChakraLink as={Link} href={link} color={"blue.400"}>
      {title}
    </ChakraLink>
  );
};

const Navbar = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen } = useDisclosure();
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();
  const route = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleLogout = (e: any) => {
    dispatch(logOut());
    route.push("/auth/signin");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box bg={useColorModeValue("gray.100", "gray.900")} px={4}>
        <Flex h={16} alignItems={"center"} justifyContent={"space-between"}>
          <Sidebar />
          <HStack spacing={8} alignItems={"center"}>
            <Box>Logo</Box>
            <HStack
              as={"nav"}
              spacing={4}
              display={{ base: "none", md: "flex" }}
            >
              {Links.map((item, index) => (
                <NavLink key={index} link={item?.link} title={item?.title} />
              ))}
            </HStack>
          </HStack>
          <Flex alignItems={"center"}>
            <Menu>
              <Button onClick={toggleColorMode}>
                {colorMode === "light" ? <MoonIcon /> : <SunIcon />}
              </Button>
              <MenuButton
                ms={4}
                as={Button}
                rounded={"full"}
                variant={"link"}
                cursor={"pointer"}
                minW={0}
              >
                <Avatar
                  size={"sm"}
                  src={
                    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493666438817-866a91353ca9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&fit=crop&h=200&w=200&s=b616b2c5b373a80ffc9636ba24f7a4a9"
                  }
                />
              </MenuButton>
              <MenuList>
                <MenuItem>Link 1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Link 2</MenuItem>
                <MenuDivider />
                <MenuItem py={0} onClick={(e) => handleLogout(e)}>
                  {/* <ChakraLink
                    as={Link}
                    href="/auth/signin"
                    color={"blue.400"}
                    display={"block"}
                    w={"100%"}
                  >
                    Logout
                  </ChakraLink> */}
                  Logout
                </MenuItem>
              </MenuList>
            </Menu>
          </Flex>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```